# how to save spfile in physical location in c#

Tags: c#, sharepoint

i need to save the spfile in physical location. for ex: c drive.

i get the file using the code below:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(item.Web.Site.ID))
 {
  using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(item.Web.ServerRelativeUrl))
   {
      SPFile file = web.GetFile(item.File.UniqueId);
   }
 }
```

now how to save file in physical location. please give some code.

Comment: I'm not into the SharePoint but the simple stramwriter will not work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `SPFile.OpenBinaryStream()` to "open" the file:

```
SPFile file = ...;
using (Stream stream = file.OpenBinaryStream())
{
  using (FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite("file path"))
  {
    // write file to the file stream here 
  }
}
```

[MSDN: SPFile.OpenBinaryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms470901.aspx)