# Binary content(BLOB) of files uploaded in sharepoint Document Library?

Tags: sharepoint

From initial R & D , I got to know that files are not physically located in Sharepoint .
Where(table field) is the binary content of Files uploaded in Document library located in SQL Server ?

There is a table 'AllDocStream' and View 'DocStream' with field named 'content' with Binary values . But I don't find corresponding File IDs etc for the record in those table and View.

What is the way if I want to access the binary content of files uploaded in Document Library ?
I want to use those binary content of files in some other application to for display/view/download of file .

Thanks and in advance .

Answer (score 1):

If you can get to the SPFile object the SharePoint C# API then you could use the code from the answer to this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230681/how-to-save-spfile-in-physical-location-in-c-sharp).

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteUrl))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
    {
        SPList list = web.Lists["Document Library Name"];

        foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)
        {
            SPFile file = item.File;
            using (Stream stream = file.OpenBinaryStream())
            {
              //Do what you want with the Stream...
            }
        }
    }
}
```